# Creating resources dependent on other existing resources

Tags: rest, api

What is the REST way of implementing a resource creation endpoint that relies on other resources?

Assume I already have the following endpoint:

```
POST items
GET items/:item_id
```

I want to create a new endpoint:

```
POST wishlists
```

To create a wishlist I will have to `POST wishlists` with a list of already-created item ids in its body.

However some items might be invalid, So I might have to report that in the response where items were not added to the newly created wishlist. Would that still be RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is RESTful API! Your case - it's just a validation of request parameters, so all good!

Response - it's up to you. But I think if you will provide something like this in payload:

```
{"errors": {
    "item1": "Invalid because of somethind 1.",
    "item3": "Invalid because of somethind 3."
}}
```

it must be verbose and clear.